# Reprojecting CORINE raster to MGI Balkan 7 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I can not save raster from CORINE land cover 2012 land use in different coordinate reference system. I want to change it to MGI Balkan 7 but I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

MGI Balkan 7 is not valid for the whole world.

You have to clip the land cover data to your country (more or less) before reprojecting to your local CRS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Global mapper to reproject your area.